# Failed to register output error for ocx

Tags: c++, visual-c++, activex, ocx

I have created one sample ocx project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. and compiled the same. i'm getting the following error,

1>Registering output (per-user redirection)...
1>Project : error PRJ0050: Failed to register output.  Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions.

I checked the UAC settings, that is in "Never Notify"

And also I tried invoking Visual Studio by "Run As Administrator" still it failed.

I tried register the OCX using regsvr32 also but its not working.

Kindly provide your suggestions to get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

Are any dependent dlls missing? When installing the ocx all dll's that are loaded by your ocx need to be present. Check with [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with Admin rights. Once I get Admin rts, i'm able to register my ocx. Thank you David.